# Clojure, replace each instance of a character with a different value from a collection

Tags: clojure

First of all, I am not sure how to easily word the title.

The problem I have is give a string `insert value here ?` I want to be able to swap the `?` with a value of my choice, i can do this using `clojure.string/replace`.

Now, the use case I require is slightly more complex, given a string like:

`these are the specified values: ?, ?, ?, ?`

I want to replace the values of the `?` with values from a collection which could look like:

`[2 389 90 13]`

so in this example the string would now read:

`these are the specified values: 2, 389, 90, 13`

so `? x` maps to `collection x` (e.g. `? 0` maps to `collection 0`)

The number of `?` will not always be 4 or a specific n, however the length of the collection will always be the same as the number of `?`.

I tried doing the following:

```
(mapv #(clojure.string/replace-first statement "?" %) [1 2 3 4])
```

But this doesn't produce the desired results in produces a `vector` of size 4 where only the first `?` is replaced by the value.

I am lost due the inability to modify variables in clojure, and I don't want to have a global string which is redefined and passed to a function `n` times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree that [DaoWen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32612564/1571406) is likely the most practical, the end of your question seems worth discussing a little as well as a matter of learning functional approaches. You're essentially looking for a way to

1. Take the initial string and the first value and use `replace-first` to make another string from them.
2. Take the result of that and the next value from the sequence and use `replace-first`on them.
3. Repeat 2 until you've gone through the entire sequence.

This is actually a classic pattern in mathematics and functional programming, called a "left fold" or "reduction" over the value sequence. Functional languages usually build it into their standard libraries as a higher order function. In Clojure it's called [`reduce`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/reduce/). Implementing your attempted strategy with it looks something like

```
(reduce #(clojure.string/replace-first %1 "?" %2) 
    "these are the specified values: ?, ?, ?, ?" 
     [2 389 90 13])
; => "these are the specified values: 2, 389, 90, 13"
```

Note that unlike your similar function literal, this takes two arguments, so that the `statement` can be rebound as we proceed through the reduction.
If you want to see what happens along the way with a `reduce`, you can swap it out with `reductions`. Here you get

```
("these are the specified values: ?, ?, ?, ?" ;After 0 applications of our replace-first fn
 "these are the specified values: 2, ?, ?, ?" ;;Intermediate value after 1 application
 "these are the specified values: 2, 389, ?, ?" ;;after 2...
 "these are the specified values: 2, 389, 90, ?"
 "these are the specified values: 2, 389, 90, 13");;Final value returned by reduce
```

Comment: I like this! Reducing with `replace-first` is a clever solution.

Answer (score 5):

There might be other considerations that aren't covered by your question—but as written, it seems like you should just be using the [string `format` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/format):

```
(apply format
       "these are the specified values: %s, %s, %s, %s"
       [2 389 90 13])
; => "these are the specified values: 2, 389, 90, 13"
```

Answer (score 1):

DaoWen has given the pragmatic answer for strings but you do have to replace your "?" with "%s" first.

But suppose this wasn't a string. Clojure has a great collection library that often means you can avoid recursion or reducers but I couldn't think of a way to do that here without getting really inefficient and messy. So here's a `reduce` solution applicable to non-strings, with lots of comments.

```
(let [original "these are the specified values: ?, ?, ?, ?"
      replacements [2 389 90 13]
      starting-accumulator [[] replacements] ; Start with an empty vector and all of the replacements.
      reducing-fn (fn [[acc [r & rs :as all-r]] o] ; Apply destructuring liberally
                    (if (= o \?) ; If original character is "?".
                      [(conj acc r) rs] ; Then add the replacement character and return the rest of the remaining replacements.
                      [(conj acc o) all-r])) ; Else add the original character and return all the remaining replacements.
      reduced (reduce reducing-fn starting-accumulator original) ; Run the reduce.
      result (first reduced) ; Get the resulting seq (discard the second item: the remaining empty seq of replacements).
      string-joined (apply str result)] ; The string was turned into a seq of chars by `reduce`. Turn it back into a string.
  string-joined)
```